# Почему @media не работает?

Tags: media-queries, css

Код:

HTML:

```
 <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width,initial-scale=1,user-scalable=no">
```

CSS:

```
 @media only screen and (max-width: 768px) {
     background-image: url('img/1.jpg');
 }
```

Не работает. Что не так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

потому что вы селектор не задали.

Какому элементу вы назначаете фон?

Comment: Все, сработало. Спасибо!